# Test SMTP Connection through AfterLogic

Tags: php, email, testing, smtp, mail-server

I'm using [AfterLogic](https://www.afterlogic.com/) mail server on my website. I am using their SDK, and I need to provide a test functionality where the user would be able to check if the settings they provided works on IMAP and SMTP.

We are able to do it on IMAP, but for SMTP, there's a bit of difficulty. We're testing SMTP by seeing if it can send an email, but to be able to do it, the correct IMAP settings must also be provided. I'm looking for a way on how to test the SMTP settings without having to go through IMAP first.

Any suggestions is highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure I understand this: you're using MailSuite Pro, correct? And since it has the same hostname for both incoming and outgoing mail (localhost if you use it locally), why do you require checking IMAP settings first?

Also, when saying that you need to check if user is able to send email, the idea is to try submitting data to SMTP server rather than just test the connectivity? Or it's more about correct authentication details for particular user account?

And feel free to request assistance at http://helpdesk.afterlogic.com/